# whenever I try to run any npm command like ng new i am getting module not found error even i have installed node version "v16.13.0"

Tags: node.js, angular

[image]

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

I tried every node versions ass well I deleted npm from c:/users/ishaan/appdata/roaming/npm

Answer (score 0):

It says the **Module not found from its internal modules**, so it means that its corrupted and Since you are on Windows Machine,

Uninstall the **current corrupted version** via the **Control Panel**, then restart your PC.
[image]

After it has restarted, It is **best** that you install it via the **executable files** from node-js's official website, download it [here](https://nodejs.org/dist/v18.15.0/node-v18.15.0-x64.msi), and you will get the Long Term Version at this time which is 18

[image: Nodejs Official Website at This Time]

Now It will be working as expected,
Thanks